# DataTables + iCheck + pagination

Tags: jquery, datatables, icheck

iCheck works with datatables only on the first page. When I navigate to any other page it shows checkboxes but they don't have iCheck applied. This code helps but doesnt' work 100%.

```
function turn_on_icheck(checkboxClass)
{
    $('input[type=checkbox]').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: checkboxClass
    });
}
$('.data-table').on('page', function() {
    turn_on_icheck();
});
```

When I go to the 2nd page it shows everything fine now, but if I go back to the page that was previously visited, the checkboxes are not there. It seems to me like it causes an error because there is already an instance of iCheck running there. Is there any way to check if there is one running or not?

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue with asp.net grid. Please use the [on draw.dt event](http://www.datatables.net/manual/events), that will help in paging and display menu as well

```
$('.data-table').on('draw.dt', function () {
    turn_on_icheck();
});
```

Comment: Glad it helped :) @reformed

Comment: Have you had any issues with having callbacks not working such as on('isChecked') when on another page, assuming you are using pagination?

Comment: I don't remember that I had issues with that but some times - with ASP.NET update panels - had to recall the things again like in that fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sonr2aje/

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler way to do this:

```
$('.inputClass').iCheck({
        handle: 'checkbox',
        checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-blue'
    });
```

[source](https://github.com/fronteed/icheck)
Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

When datatables refresh the values, new inputs are render and the inputs need to apply again the icheck funtion.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').iCheck({
        checkboxClass: checkboxClass
    });
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation on how this solves the issue

Comment: When datatables refresh the values, new inputs are render and the inputs need to apply again the icheck funtion.

Comment: You can edit the question and add it the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Do this (write your code in "drawCallback" function):

```
...
'drawCallback': function(settings) {
     $('.i-checks').iCheck({
         checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green'
     });
 },
 ...
```

It solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solved it... you should give the icheck some time until it finishes before calling the DataTable function... use the JQUERY's when function

```
function Typer(callback)
{    
    if ($("input.flat")[0]) 
    {
        $('input.flat').iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green',
            radioClass: 'iradio_flat-green'
        });
    }
}


function enableDataTableMain()
    {
    var table = $('#tableWithData').DataTable({
     "aoColumnDefs": [
        {
            'bSortable': false,
            'aTargets': [0]
        } //disables sorting for column one
    ],
    "tableTools": {
        "sSwfPath": "swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
    }});                    
    var tt = new $.fn.dataTable.TableTools( table );
    $( tt.fnContainer() ).insertBefore('div.functionDiv');
}


    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.when( Typer() ).done(function() {
       enableDataTableMain();
    });
});
```